# ALSA audio and YouTube

Tags: linux, flash, audio, youtube, alsa

I want to play youtube videos and programmatically direct firefox's audio out to a particular sound card.

I think I would do something like `firefox | aplay -D hw:x,y.`
Yields:

> Playing raw data 'stdin' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
>   aplay: set_params:1059: Sample format non available
>   Available formats:
>   - S16_LE

Trying `firefox | aplay -D hw:1,0 -f S16_LE -c 2`

> Playing raw data 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Stereo
>   Warning: rate is not accurate (requested = 8000Hz, got = 44100Hz)
>            please, try the plug plugin

Finally, `firefox | aplay -D plughw:1,0 -f S16_LE -c 2`

> Playing raw data 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Stereo

The command-line suggests that it worked, but audio came out of hw:0,0 (the default).

Do I need to make my own plugin?
Or do I need to force alsa to take 44100Hz?

Also, I refuse to use pulse since the memory leak bug makes it crash often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure flash always uses the default sound card, so you need to change `pcm.default`. You could do so by editing `~/.asoundrc` and adding something like:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 2
}
```

Of course, that affects all apps, but I believe can also set `ALSA_CONFIG_PATH` (in the environment) to specify a different file, so you could do it for just Firefox.

The [ALSA FAQ](http://alsa.opensrc.org/FAQ026) indicates there are `ALSA_PCM_CARD` and `ALSA_CARD` environment variables that may work as well.

These variables actually work because they're part of the default also config in `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`:

```
    @args.CARD {
            type string
            default {
                    @func getenv
                    vars [
                            ALSA_PCM_CARD
                            ALSA_CARD
                    ]
                    default {
                            @func refer
                            name defaults.pcm.card
                    }
            }
    }
```

So, you should be able to do this:

```
ALSA_PCM_CARD=1 ALSA_PCM_DEVICE=3 firefox
```

using the appropriate card and device numbers from your system. Or of course you could add your own environment variable (or other conditional check) into your ALSA configuration.

Comment: This is great. I couldn't get the environmental env to work, but it seems equivalent to just changing out the .asoundrc file programmatically before I open firefox.

Comment: I would also want to be more sure that firefox can't play out of anything that isn't "default." I find it hard to believe that I can't pipe that out to a different device

Comment: @cyrusv: The sound data doesn't go to STDOUT, so you can't pipe it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Flash uses its own output config, independent of Firefox. Define FLASH_ALSA_DEVICE before running your browser, it tells Flash what ALSA PCM to use instead of the default.